# Angular parent component "scoping" child component

Tags: javascript, angular

Suppose I have components `Parent` and `Child`.  `Child` can be used either as a standalone component, or within a `Parent` component.  However, I want `Child` to have different behavior based upon where it lives.

Suppose `Child` has an optional `@Input [isHappy]`, which is either `true` or `false`.  **However**, whenever a `Child` component is hosted by a `Parent` component, suppose `isHappy` must always be true.

AFAICT there are two ways of doing this:

1) User must **just know** to always specify `[isHappy]="true"` whenever a `Child` is hosted by a `Parent`.

```
<parent>
  <child [isHappy]="true"></child>
</parent>
```

2) `Parent` manually sets `this.child.isHappy = true` within its `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook.

**Which approach is preferred?**  In my opinion, approach #2 makes more sense, users don't have to know to set `[isHappy]="true"` when a `Child` is hosted by a `Parent`.  On the other hand, I'm aware that it's frowned upon in Angular for components to programmatically change one another, especially if all components are `OnPush` (please correct me if I'm wrong here).

Comment: Why not inject the parent component into the child as described [here](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-navtree)

Comment: I don't like that solution because then the `Child` contains logic based upon where it is living. Preferably the `Child` should be completely agnostic as to where it is, and shouldn't contain any branching logic based upon who's hosting it.

Answer (score 0):

> I want Child to have different behavior based upon where it lives.

How about letting `Child` component know where it lives with `ElementRef`:

```ts
export class ChildComponent {
  hasParent: boolean;

  constructor (
    private elRef: ElementRef
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const el = this.elRef.nativeElement.parentElement as HTMLElement
    this.hasParent = el.localName === 'app-parent'
  }
}
```

stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kagdsu

Comment: Hm, same suggestion again. See my comment on the original question for why I don't love this approach.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion 2nd way would work, but that could add couple of things into your solution

1. Tight coupling between two component
2. What if `parent` component don't have `child` component?

To solve it by better way, I'd suggest you to use `Host` decorator, that will ask for `Parent` component dependency from `Child` component. If that exists the make `isHappy` property to be `true`

```
@Component({...})
export class Child {
   @Input() isHappy: boolean = false;

   constructor(@Optional() @Host() private parent: Parent) {} 

   ngOnInit() {
      // Do only if parent exists
      if (this.parent) {
         this.parent.isHappy = true
      }
   }
}
```

---

I understand even the way suggested above has tight coupling between the `Parent` component. We should think of removing that dependency from the inner child component.

Yes, we can do that by little hackish way, where we would be checking current component's immediate parent component name like below. For achieving the same you had to add `ViewContainerRef` dependency to get hold of parent/host component.

```
constructor(private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef) {}

ngOnInit() {
    if(this.viewContainer[ '_data' ].componentView.parent.component.constructor.name === 'Parent') {
      this.parent.isHappy = true
    }
}
```

Comment: See my comment above on the original question as to why I don't love this approach.  Suppose `Parent` components require `Child` components, then is approach #2 okay?

Comment: @sir_thursday even I thought about the same after writing an answer.. still it was having tight coupling with `Parent` component. I've digged little in code, and found some hackish solution. Kindly have a look at it. Thanks for heads up :)

Comment: Thanks for the update Pankaj. Unfortunately I'm not sure I completely understand your new proposed solution. Those are the Child's constructor and ngOnInit hook, no? So the Child still has logic that depends upon whether or not its hosted by a Parent component. I don't see how this solves any of my original concerns. :\